# Cannot boot from cd

Tags: windows-7

Hi can any body help me I had win7 on my desktop then I install Linux but didn't like it so I want to install win 7 again but now it gives me a ' cannot boot from cd code 5 ' wait can I do to fix it

Answer (score 0):

A couple questions:

Have you ever successfully used this CD to install Windows 7 before? 
Have you ever installed it to this machine?

I ask because generally this error because either the boot sector isn't burned on to the CD or the CD was not burnt properly. Also some motherboards do not support booting from CD (though that mostly applies to very old ones).

I would try burning the CD again and follow the instructions exactly.

[Install Windows 7 preventing code 5 error](http://www.unawave.de/windows-7-tipps/code5-error.html)

Or, you could try doing an install from a flash drive:

[How to install Windows 7 from flash drive](http://kmwoley.com/blog/creating-bootable-vista-windows-7-usb-flash-drive/)

Comment: For the sake of improvement, you need to make some edits. Asking clarifying questions should be done in the comments area below the question so the answer space can be solely used for...well...answers. Also, links are not good answers because they can stop working. Best practice is to write the basics of the answer here and use a link to cite your source.